# How do I align text with the edge of the box?

Tags: text, alignment, css

I want to align some text above the edge of a box.

The box is an inline-block element and the text I want to align is `<h2>2014 Pictures!</h2>`.

This is what it looks like right now.

http://jsfiddle.net/Zr5yt/3/

As you can see the problem is the text is veering left.

I would like it if `2014 pictures!` could start above the edge of the picture box. I've been stuck on this for days now; can anyone help?

HTML

```
 <title>Picture Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/grid.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <link href='<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">

  <body>
    <div class="container clearfix">
      <div class="grid_12">
        <h1>Picture Gallery</h1>
      </div>  
      <div class="grid_3">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="first"><a href="#">Project 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Project 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Project 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Project 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Project 5</a></li>
          <li class="last"><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="grid_9 omega">
        <h2>Introduction</h2>
        <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 

        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </p> 

        <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text </p>

        <a href="#" class="btn"> Click to learn about me</a>
      </div> 


      <div id="gallery" class="grid_12">
        <h2>2014 Pictures!</h2>
        <img src="img/1 crop.jpg" alt="Picture"> 

        <img src="img/2 crop.jpg" alt="Picture">

        <p><a href="#" class="btn-small"> For more photos click here </a></p>

      </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

STYLE CSS

```
      body {
    font-family:'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    color: #FF00DB;
    background: #A1B3FA ;
  }

  a {
    color: #0000FF;
    text-decoration: none;

  }

  h1 {
    font-size: 5em;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    text-align: center;

  }

  h2 {
    font-size: 1.750em;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    margin: 20px 20px 0 0;
    text-align: left;
  }

  .btn {
    color: #FF0000;
    background: #4FB69F url('img/texture.png') no-repeat right top;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0 0;
    border-radius: 40px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }

  .btn:hover {
    background-color: #4c4756;
  }

  ul.nav {
    margin-right: 20px;
    list-style: circle;
    float: left;
  }

  ul.nav li {
    margin-bottom: 0px; 
  }


  #gallery {
    clear: both;
     text-align: center;

  }


  #gallery img{
    border: 8px solid;
    color: #0000FF;
    margin: 40px 0px 0px 0px;
  }
```

GRID CSS

```
.grid_1 { width: 65px; }
.grid_2 { width: 150px; }
.grid_3 { width: 235px; }
.grid_4 { width: 320px; }
.grid_5 { width: 405px; }
.grid_6 { width: 490px; }
.grid_7 { width: 575px; }
.grid_8 { width: 660px; }
.grid_9 { width: 745px; }
.grid_10 { width: 830px; }
.grid_11 { width: 915px; }
.grid_12 { width: 1000px; }

.grid_1,
.grid_2,
.grid_3,
.grid_4,
.grid_5,
.grid_6,
.grid_7,
.grid_8,
.grid_9,
.grid_10,
.grid_11,
.grid_12 {
    margin: 0 20px 10px 0;
    float:left;
    display: block;
}

.alpha{margin-left:0px;}
.omega{margin-right:0px;}

.container{
    width: 1000px; 
    margin: auto;
}



.clear{clear:both;display:block;overflow:hidden;visibility:hidden;width:0;height:0}.clearfix:after{clear:both;content:' ';display:block;font-size:0;line-height:0;visibility:hidden;width:0;height:0}* html .clearfix,*:first-child+html .clearfix{zoom:1}
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zr5yt/7/)

just added

```
 #gallery h2 {
      text-align:center;
  }
```

is this the way you wanted?

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. I'm actually trying to get the text to start above the box's edge. So the text '2014' and the box are both vertically aligned. I just don't know how to align them both. Is this any clearer?

Comment: This blog talks about doing the same thing but I'm not sure what code I need to put it into html. I think it might have something to do with making the margins vertically aligned. http://blog.lynda.com/2013/01/10/indesign-secrets-understanding-optical-margin-alignment/

Comment: You can show what you want to do using a picture, sorry to say but I didn't get you and my English is weak